# How to add custom css in Primefaces 3.5?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here's a snippet of my code!

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Associate Management Pool</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/default.css" />
</h:head>
```

Comment: Duplicate. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css

Comment: Thanks, I got it anyways.